# Can a stranger do anything malicious if I add them as a user on my PS3?

Tags: ps3

I bought a digital download of a PS3 game on ebay, but instead of sending me a code or key or something, the seller gave me a Sony Entertainment Network username and password. His instructions were to create a new user, choosing this account for it, then download the game and then sign back in as me and play the game.

(This is all a bit shady, I thought, but the game was a good deal, and I don't mind a few hoops at the start if it's technically legit).

But can the seller do anything to my PS3 or saved games or my own account if I do this?

Can he just wait a few months (to avoid bad feedback) and then remove my access to the game by removing my PS3 from his account?

**Edit:** Got refund easily through eBay. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm interested to hear how people answer.  I suspect there is something shady going on with this exchange.

Comment: Yeah, you got swindled. You're also violation the PSN terms of use. (So is he)

Comment: I would try to recover your money if at all possible. You were scammed.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing the eBay listing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38507/discussion-on-question-by-mgowen-can-a-stranger-do-anything-malicious-if-i-add-t).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is more than likely that the person you "bought" the game from owns a digital license on their own PSN account.  The way the system works is that you can buy a game from the PSN store once, but then download it on up to 5 different systems.

The seller wants you to take advantage of this policy by logging in as them, downloading the game, and using up one of the downloads.  This is a total abuse of the policy and likely against the PSN EULA.

You can read a little bit more about this topic here: [Sony getting stricter on PS3 and PSP game sharing](http://www.gamespot.com/articles/sony-getting-stricter-on-ps3-and-psp-game-sharing/1100-6344077/) and why it is a bad idea here: [Why you should not game share](http://community.us.playstation.com/t5/PlayStation-General/Why-you-should-not-game-share/td-p/37577861).

> Game sharing is a violation of the terms of service of the PSN and
>   your account can be temporarily banned and/or suspended and with
>   multiple infractions you could become permanently banned and lose
>   access to all online progress and more importantly, all the money you
>   spent to buy those games would be rendered useless.

Answer (score 33):

You didn't buy anything, because he didn't sell anything.

You can't resell digital downloads like a physical disk. It's right there in the EULA that no one ever reads, because you aren't buying the game, you're buying a conditional license to play the game. Your customer rights don't extend to redistribution. With most EULAs, unauthorized redistribution is grounds to terminate your license.

So basically this guy sold you something he had no right or ability to sell you. He can continue to play his game, or "sell" it to somebody else, or change his login credentials. And if anybody from Sony finds out, his account could get deleted, so you, at best, can't play the game anymore, either. At worst they delete your account, too.

What do you do? Try to get your money back and don't buy digital downloads from a third party in the future.

Comment: Although technically not the question he asked this is the answer he needs. This is a scam and you need to report it to Ebay and get your money back.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it would probably be legit because it's sold on eBay, where it's so easy to get a refund, and there's actually plenty of digital games selling and trading on PC - legit keys from actual boxed games sold in a cheaper region like Russia, and people gifting steam games to each other in trades, etc. I suppose sometimes those may be technically against the terms of a EULA too, though. Nevermind, I can easily get a refund through eBay. Thanks.